# Extract text from RTF data using PHP

Tags: php, parsing, converters, rtf

I've looked all over and tried a few different things, but I just can't seem to correctly get just the text (with linbreaks) out of some RTF data.  Currently I am using [this PHP function](http://webcheatsheet.com/php/reading_the_clean_text_from_rtf.php).

I am writing something that will extract song lyrics from a file that stores RTF data.  Here is a sample input line:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1038\cocoasubrtf350
{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
\pard\tx560\tx1120\tx1680\tx2240\tx2800\tx3360\tx3920\tx4480\tx5040\tx5600\tx6160\tx6720\qc\pardirnatural

\f0\fs96 \cf1 Be near O God\
Be near O God of us\
Your nearness is to us our good\
Be near O God\
Be near O God of us\
Your nearness is to us our good\
Our good}
```

And then running it through the linked function above produces this:

```
  Be near O GodBe near O God of usYour nearness is to us our goodBe near O GodBe near O God of usYour nearness is to us our goodOur good
```

It gets the text, but it also removes all the line breaks in a way that isn't useful. It doesn't show up here, but it also has several leading line breaks for some reason.

Any ideas on how to properly parse this RTF data with PHP while preserving line breaks?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

 function rtf_isPlainText($s) {
    $arrfailAt = array("*", "fonttbl", "colortbl", "datastore", "themedata");
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($arrfailAt); $i++)
        if (!empty($s[$arrfailAt[$i]])) return false;
    return true;
} 

function rtf2txt($filename) {
    // Read the data from the input file.
    $text = file_get_contents($filename);
    if (!strlen($text))
        return "";

    // Create empty stack array.
    $document = "";
    $stack = array();
    $j = -1;
    // Read the data character-by- character…
    for ($i = 0, $len = strlen($text); $i < $len; $i++) {
        $c = $text[$i];

        // Depending on current character select the further actions.
        switch ($c) {
            // the most important key word backslash
            case "\\":
                // read next character
                $nc = $text[$i + 1];

                // If it is another backslash or nonbreaking space or hyphen,
                // then the character is plain text and add it to the output stream.
                if ($nc == '\\' && rtf_isPlainText($stack[$j])) $document .= '\\';
                elseif ($nc == '~' && rtf_isPlainText($stack[$j])) $document .= ' ';
                elseif ($nc == '_' && rtf_isPlainText($stack[$j])) $document .= '-';
                // If it is an asterisk mark, add it to the stack.
                elseif ($nc == '*') $stack[$j]["*"] = true;
                // If it is a single quote, read next two characters that are the hexadecimal notation
                // of a character we should add to the output stream.
                elseif ($nc == "'") {
                    $hex = substr($text, $i + 2, 2);
                    if (rtf_isPlainText($stack[$j]))
                        $document .= html_entity_decode("&#".hexdec($hex).";");
                    //Shift the pointer.
                    $i += 2;
                // Since, we’ve found the alphabetic character, the next characters are control word
                // and, possibly, some digit parameter.
                } elseif ($nc >= 'a' && $nc <= 'z' || $nc >= 'A' && $nc <= 'Z') {
                    $word = "";
                    $param = null;

                    // Start reading characters after the backslash.
                    for ($k = $i + 1, $m = 0; $k < strlen($text); $k++, $m++) {
                        $nc = $text[$k];
                        // If the current character is a letter and there were no digits before it,
                        // then we’re still reading the control word. If there were digits, we should stop
                        // since we reach the end of the control word.
                        if ($nc >= 'a' && $nc <= 'z' || $nc >= 'A' && $nc <= 'Z') {
                            if (empty($param))
                                $word .= $nc;
                            else
                                break;
                        // If it is a digit, store the parameter.
                        } elseif ($nc >= '0' && $nc <= '9')
                            $param .= $nc;
                        // Since minus sign may occur only before a digit parameter, check whether
                        // $param is empty. Otherwise, we reach the end of the control word.
                        elseif ($nc == '-') {
                            if (empty($param))
                                $param .= $nc;
                            else
                                break;
                        } else
                            break;
                    }
                    // Shift the pointer on the number of read characters.
                    $i += $m - 1;

                    // Start analyzing what we’ve read. We are interested mostly in control words.
                    $toText = "";
                    switch (strtolower($word)) {
                        // If the control word is "u", then its parameter is the decimal notation of the
                        // Unicode character that should be added to the output stream.
                        // We need to check whether the stack contains \ucN control word. If it does,
                        // we should remove the N characters from the output stream.
                        case "u":
                            $toText .= html_entity_decode("&#x".dechex($param).";");
                            $ucDelta = @$stack[$j]["uc"];
                            if ($ucDelta > 0)
                                $i += $ucDelta;
                        break;
                        // Select line feeds, spaces and tabs.
                        case "par": case "page": case "column": case "line": case "lbr":
                            $toText .= "\n"; 
                        break;
                        case "emspace": case "enspace": case "qmspace":
                            $toText .= " "; 
                        break;
                        case "tab": $toText .= "\t"; break;
                        // Add current date and time instead of corresponding labels.
                        case "chdate": $toText .= date("m.d.Y"); break;
                        case "chdpl": $toText .= date("l, j F Y"); break;
                        case "chdpa": $toText .= date("D, j M Y"); break;
                        case "chtime": $toText .= date("H:i:s"); break;
                        // Replace some reserved characters to their html analogs.
                        case "emdash": $toText .= html_entity_decode("&mdash;"); break;
                        case "endash": $toText .= html_entity_decode("&ndash;"); break;
                        case "bullet": $toText .= html_entity_decode("&#149;"); break;
                        case "lquote": $toText .= html_entity_decode("&lsquo;"); break;
                        case "rquote": $toText .= html_entity_decode("&rsquo;"); break;
                        case "ldblquote": $toText .= html_entity_decode("&laquo;"); break;
                        case "rdblquote": $toText .= html_entity_decode("&raquo;"); break;
                        // Add all other to the control words stack. If a control word
                        // does not include parameters, set &param to true.
                        default:
                            $stack[$j][strtolower($word)] = empty($param) ? true : $param;
                        break;
                    }
                    // Add data to the output stream if required.
                    if (rtf_isPlainText($stack[$j]))
                        $document .= $toText;
                }

                $i++;
            break;
            // If we read the opening brace {, then new subgroup starts and we add
            // new array stack element and write the data from previous stack element to it.
            case "{":
                array_push($stack, $stack[$j++]);
            break;
            // If we read the closing brace }, then we reach the end of subgroup and should remove 
            // the last stack element.
            case "}":
                array_pop($stack);
                $j--;
            break;
            // Skip “trash”.
            case '\0': case '\r': case '\f': case '\n': break;
            // Add other data to the output stream if required.
            default:
                if (rtf_isPlainText($stack[$j]))
                    $document .= $c;
            break;
        }
    }
    // Return result.
    return $document;
}

echo rtf2txt('here is your file path');
?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  You just copied the entire function and added one line at the bottom.  I know how to call the function, my question was about the fact that this function isn't doing what I want.  Maybe I'm missing what your point was?

Comment: @ChrisBarr from what I remember I modified that function cause of some minor issues and worked like a charm on php 5.1!